# Change UIView size without scale with animation

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

Is there a way to change the size (width and height) of a `UIView` without scale?
For example:

If I have my `customview` and I want to animate the resize from:

```
customview.frame.width = 100
customview.frame.height = 50
```

To:

```
customview.frame.width = 100
customview.frame.height = 200
```

Can I do it using `UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7, animations: {`?

Right now I only find examples with scale, like this:

```
let originalTransform = self.main.transform
let scaledTransform = originalTransform.scaledBy(x: 0.2, y: 0.2)
let scaledAndTranslatedTransform = scaledTransform.translatedBy(x: 0.0, y: -250.0)
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7, animations: {
    self.main.transform = scaledAndTranslatedTransform
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems too obvious so it may not be what you want, but simply set the view's update frame in the animation block.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7, animations: {
    self.main.frame = someNewRect
})
```

No transforms required.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!